# with just four element getting the Memory error in python

Tags: python

I have been getting the memory error but unable to understand the reason behind that. Below is the code. Using the list and appending just two more elements in the list.

```
mylist = ['phonon', 'communication']
for i in mylist:
    mylist.append(i.upper())
print(mylist)
```

It will be really very helpful if anyone can help me with that.

Comment: It is generally bad practice to change list size during iteration. With your logic, there will always be a next element, so it will run until there is no more memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in mylist:
    mylist.append(i.upper())
```

is basically appending to your list while iterating on it. So the iteration never ends.

You want to do:

```
mylist += [i.upper() for i in mylist]
```

in that last case, the right-hand expression is computed from a non-modified `mylist`, then its elements are appended to the existing `mylist`.

note that the above is equivalent to

```
mylist.extend([i.upper() for i in mylist])
```

or

```
mylist.extend(list(map(str.upper,mylist)))
```

note that for both snippets above it is *necessary* to convert to `list`, or you get the same memory error if the inside is lazily evaluated. The last snippet is probably the fastest because it doesn't use any python loops at all, `map`, and no `lambda`

For all 3 snippets the result is:

```
['phonon', 'communication', 'PHONON', 'COMMUNICATION']
```

Comment: Does this unpack the newly created list? On sight I would expect this to end up with `mylist = ['phonon', 'communication', ['PHONON', 'COMMUNICATION']]`.

Comment: it doesn't unpack it extends the original list. A variant is `mylist.extend([...])`. Your result is achieved by using `.append`

Comment: @Jean this doesn't unpack the array, and hence doesn't work.

Comment: If you try something like [1,2]+=[3,4], that won't work. Hence, you need to use extend

Comment: what do you mean? have you tried it? it works perfectly, like extend.

Comment: So `+=` works like `extend()` rather than `append()`? Interesting.

Comment: I'm using 3.4, if that makes a difference

Comment: "I'm getting an error" isn't a valid error report. And the code above works. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @BramVanroy yes, += works like extend. It's the same in place addition

Answer (score 0):

I would add your edited elements to a new list:

```
uppers = []

for i in mylist:
    uppers.append(i.upper())

print(uppers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off Jean's answer:

```
mylist.extend(i.upper() for i in mylist)
```

Should give you the desired result.